# Decimal places in DocumentDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to add to documentDB document with property:

```
"Value": 849.30000000000007
```

After using `CreateDocumentAsync` method for add document to documentDB, in my collection have number without last digit:

```
"Value": 849.3000000000001
```

How can I add this property right? Thanks for help.

Comment: I assume it's being stored as a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point number - at which point, the two values you've specified are equivalent, basically. If you need that degree of precision, you probably don't want to be using binary floating point...

Answer (score 3):

As Jon pointed out, JavaScript has one number type Number, a 64-bit IEEE 754 float which is often referred to as a "double". You could use strings to represent it as a true decimal. Then you'll have to resort to a 3rd party decimal library (like [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js) for node.js, or the equivalent for your platform) to do any maths on the values.

Alternatively, you may be able to use integers and assume a particular exponent (think scientific notation) or store the exponent in another field. Again, this poses problems for doing maths on it.